# How to extract href url from html anchor using lxml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I try to extract the next page href string using lxml.

For example I try to extract the "/review/bulb.co.uk?b=MTYxOTg5MDE1OTAwMHw2MDhkOGZlZmY5ZjQ4NzA4ZTA4MWI2Mzk" from the html in the following example:

```
<nav rel="nav" class="pagination-container AjaxPager">
    <a href="/review/bulb.co.uk?b=MTYxOTg5MDE1OTAwMHw2MDhkOGZlZmY5ZjQ4NzA4ZTA4MWI2Mzk" data-page-number="next-page" class="button button--primary next-page" rel="next" data-track-link="{'target': 'Company profile', 'name': 'navigation', 'navigationType': 'next'}">
Next page
    </a>
</nav>
```

I have tried the following but it returns a list not the string that I am looking for:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as html

URL = https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/bulb.co.uk
page = requests.get(URL)

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

href = tree.xpath('//a/@href')
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The XPath returns all hrefs of all anchors. If you only want one, have you tried `tree.xpath('//a/@href')[0]`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am looking for a way to extract the href for the <a> that has this class: class="button button--primary next-page". There is no guarantee that the href I am looking for will have the same index on the list every time.

Comment: Use beautifulsoup rather than lxml directly if you want to parse html classes

Comment: Or you can use `contains(@class` solution, as shown in your previous question answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making this change to your code

```
href = tree.xpath('//a[@class="button button--primary next-page"]/@href')
href[0]
```

Gives me this output:

```
'/review/bulb.co.uk?b=MTYxOTk1ODMxMzAwMHw2MDhlOWEyOWY5ZjQ4NzA4ZTA4MjMxNTE'
```

which is close to the output in your question (its value may change dynamically).

Comment: To expand on this, it would be helpful to read about xpath predicates.